# Multiple condition window width and

Tags: jquery, width, scrolltop

I'm trying to trigger a class removal based on two conditions : a window with less than 760 px and a scroll > 0.

Here's my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var $windowWidth = window.innerWidth
    }
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if (($(window).scrollTop() > 0) && ($windowWidth <= 760)) {
            $("nav").removeClass("horizontal").addClass("vertical");
        }
    });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: And your question is... and your problem is....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/megedawu/2/edit)**

You don't need 2 classes, only one, the `.vertical` supposing the default is the other.

```
<nav class="horizontal">NAV</nav>
```

You were close, create a function:

```
function checkWin(){
  var winInnW = window.innerWidth;
  var winScrT = $(window).scrollTop();
  var s0w760  = winScrT>0 && winInnW<=760; // Boolean
  $("nav").toggleClass("vertical", s0w760);
}

checkWin(); // on DOM ready also
$(window).on('resize scroll', checkWin);
```

---

if you feel comfortable here's a oneliner

```
function checkWin(){
   $("nav").toggleClass("vertical", $(window).scrollTop()>0 && window.innerWidth<=760);
}
```

Comment: Great Roko! Thanks a lot! The class removal is triggered by your code! How can I un-trigger it when the user scroll back to top though? I would like to go back to adding the vertical class when the user scrolls back on top! Is this possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: thanks a lot for your smart answer! Hope i can get to your level one day!! Thanks again!